# MSBuild task for Silverlight unit testing

Tags: silverlight, msbuild

We have automated build environment which uses MSBuild task to launch NUnit test. How can I launch unit test written with Silverlight Unit Test framework? Is there a MSBuild task available?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Silverlight Unit Test Framework found in the Silverlight Toolkit, there is a build task to automate launching the browser.

Unfortunately there are some issues with the April release that may prevent it from working in app situations, but the previous November release worked pretty well on Windows Vista and Windows 7 machines. A fix is pending for the new version.

Comment: The tests are run as part of build process on continuous integration server. If there is any unit test failures the build fails as well. Would I be able to achieve same when launching test in a browser?

Comment: Yes that was the idea of the task originally, but reporting is not integreated: the MSbuild script may indicate failures, but there will not be an easy list. It may at least be a start; the source to the tasks are included in the Infrastructure.zip file to make changes as fit.

Answer (score 0):

No, beyond "community tasks" and such - there is not something like you describe.  But why not write your own?  Writing custom msbuild tasks is easy. :)